# Update data from database from data got from database

Tags: php

I am trying to generate pin and serial number stored in database and display base on demand. For example, if someone needs 1 or 2 pin and serial number,  after dispaying those pin and serial number, I want to update their value so that it can't be generated again. I have trouble updating the value.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['card']) && isset($_POST['cn'])) {
    $card = $_POST['card'];
    $no_of_pin = $_POST['cn'];
    if (!empty($card) && !empty($cn)){
        $query =mysql_query("SELECT id, pin, sn FROM pin_test WHERE value = '0' LIMIT $no_of_pin");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            echo 'PIN: ' .$row['pin'].  ' SN:'. $row['sn']. ' id:'. $row['id'].'<br>';

        $pin = $row['pin'];
        $sn = $row['sn'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        $query2 = "UPDATE pin_test SET value = '1' WHERE id = $id";
        if(mysql_query($query2)){
            echo 'Successful';
        }else{
            echo 'Unsuccessful';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'All fields are required.';        
    }
}                 
?>
```

Comment: Please format your code properly for the next time. You can't expect us to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following syntax:
**UPDATED:**
    $query2 = "UPDATE `pin_test` SET `value`=1 WHERE `id`='$id'";

Comment: Please do the following: 

    $test = mysql_query($query2);
    var_dump($test);

and share the results here

Comment: So your query is still not working; 
Can you make sure $id is not empty ?

Comment: also try :

mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Id is not empty...  Please i want u to help me..  Even if u want a payment..  I will..  From html request form the user will select the pin name and the numbers of pin...  Please look at the code well from  the beginning u will really understand and maybe from the u will know where the people is from..  When user selects more than one pin..  The query will generate pins in array..  The pins are displaying but the value is not updating...  Please

Comment: try : mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error()); 
It will help us detect the problem.

Also i will send you recommendations after we fix the issue for why you shouldn't use this method anymore

Comment: When I use WHERE Id = '$id'  it will show bool(true) but it won't update value but when I use Id = $id it shows you have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near" at line 1.

Comment: But what if I give u an idea of what I wanna achieve or do..  Won't it be of help?

Comment: Sure, the $id should be between quotations for the syntax to be correct. 
You can tell me what you need to achieve, but here, it's only to answer this particular question and not fix the whole thing. 

can you tell me what's the type of "value" in your db? Also please make sure value is between quotation in your query  'value', as it is a keyword :))

Comment: Okay...  I want to do a program that generates pin and serial number from database and made sure that those generated pins are not displayed again for another user...  That's why I wanted to query the database so that I can can only display pins and serial numbers that has the value of zero..  Will that help?

Comment: Yeah i got that from the initial explanation, can you please show me $query2 that you have right now?

Comment: The value in dB is 0 and 1... I upload the pins and serial numbers and value..  Which is zero after generating the numbers..  I want to update 0 to 1

Comment: In your database structure, is value a string or an integer? 

Also can you please copy paste your Query here?

Comment: $query2 = "update pin_test set value ='1' where Id= '$id'"

Comment: Replace it by this 

$query2 = "update pin_test set 'value' ='1' where Id= '$id'"

Comment: $query2 = "UPDATE pin_test SET value = '1' WHERE id = '$id' ";
$test=(mysql_query($query2) or die (mysql_error()));
var_dump($test);

Comment: I believe its the same with what u wrote?

Comment: Notice value vs 'value'

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''value' = '1' WHERE id = ''' at line 1

Comment: so what should i do? is there a better way to achieve this aim? please

Comment: can you try this please? as it is: 

$query2 = "UPDATE `pin_test` SET `value`='1' WHERE `id`='$id'";

Comment: There is no error message but the database value is not updated

Comment: Now try this: "UPDATE pin_test SET 'value' =1 WHERE id='$id'";

Comment: this is the error mesaage after trying it....You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''value' = '1' WHERE id = ''' at line 1

Comment: kindly go to: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90789/mysql-query-issue  i will continue chatting with you to fix this issue over there

Comment: I don't have upto 20 reputation..  They say I can't chat there

Comment: Oh okay, well in your last reply i noticed that there's a blank empty space after id;  i will update my initial answer, please copy the query as it is from there and try it

Comment: Can you upload your php file to google drive or dropbox and send me the link so i can take a look at it ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B09j9BzxHwRNZnB1dTdueXVPaDg thats the link..

Comment: I don't have access to the folder, kindly "share" the file with me

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B09j9BzxHwRNLVR2M3hBRmxHcUE&usp=sharing  have open sharing.. if u cant open it,... please give me ur gmail address

Comment: are u able to u open it?

Comment: Find the updated file here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8qxrEjW1tYFWEpPSFJpZTBhaE0&usp=sharing

Copy it as it is.

Comment: Wow..  Thanks..  Let me check

Comment: its still showing this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''value' = 1 WHERE 'id' =''' at line 1

Comment: try this now: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8qxrEjW1tYFZ1pqSHZ6WEZ2bDA/view?usp=sharing  should work

Comment: its showed successful but the value in database didnt change

Comment: It's successful but the value in unchanged in database

Comment: My advice is try to use mysqli instead of mysql; you can find a good tutorial here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC8QFjACahUKEwj00N2f4pvIAhWItRoKHXDFCxw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcodular.com%2Fphp-mysqli&usg=AFQjCNG7lPQytQv9l9iZOXh6vIT1sG1Sjw&sig2=HPkcWop14YNLas0caopcMg  mysql_query is deprecated; try to implement mysqli instead in your project

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical error which runs but doesn't really affect the table.

Try doing it like this:

```
$query2 = "UPDATE pin_test SET value='1' WHERE id='$id'";
```